# Can I use strip! and chomp! in one line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I see that `strip!` and `chomp!` (and other similar methods) return `nil` when the string is not altered.  This apparently forbids combining these methods in one line:

```
s = 'a' # => "a"   
s.strip!.chomp!(',')  
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp!' for nil:NilClass
```

So I seem to be forced to write one per line:

```
s.strip! # => nil  
s.chomp!(',') # => nil
```

Is this the only way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the non-mutating versions of those methods:

```
s = s.strip.chomp(',')
```

You could use a semicolon (but that would usually be poor taste):

```
s.strip!; s.chomp!(',')
```

Comment: If `s.strip!; s.chomp!(','); s` is in poor taste, how would you characterize `(s.strip! || s) && (s.chomp!(',') || s)`?

Comment: That would be poorer taste.   Also, `s.strip! || s.chomp!(',')` would work if we rely on `strip!` always returning nil.

Comment: That's not a problem: `(s.strip! && nil) || s.chomp!(',')`. :-) I think it's time to sleep.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case where [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) could be a useful tool:

`s.tap {|t| t.strip!}.chomp!`

Comment: You can shorten it to `s.tap(&:strip!).chomp!`.

Comment: You can lengthen it to `s.tap(&:strip!).tap { |s| s.chomp!(',') }` (to return the processed string).

Answer (score 0):

```
 R = /
     ^\s+ # match >= 1 whitespace at the beginning of string
     |     # or
     ,\s*$ # match comma then >= 0 whitespace at the end of the line
     |     # or 
     \s+$  # match >= 1 whitespace at the end of the line
     /x

def clean(s)
  s.gsub!(R,'') || s
end
```

In all of the following, the return value is `"ab"`, which is also the new value of the string:

```
clean '  ab  '
clean '  ab,'
clean ' ab,  '
clean 'ab,'
clean 'ab'
```